# streamOut.FlushAsync() not implemented exception

Tags: usb, uwp, notimplementedexception

I am working on USB communication UWP APP. I can get SerialDevice instance without problem, but when I call myDevice.OutputStream.FlushAsync() I get not Implemented exception.

Here is my code

```
private async void EstablishConButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var DeviceSelector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
        var Devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceSelector);
        var deviceInfo = Devices.FirstOrDefault();

        SerialDevice myDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);

        if (myDevice == null)
        {
            Debugg("Device not found!");
            return;
        }
        Debugg("Device found!");

        byte[] buffer = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05 , 0x05 , 0x05 , 0x05 , 0x05 , 0x05 };
        var rBuffer = (buffer).AsBuffer();
        await myDevice.OutputStream.WriteAsync(rBuffer);

        await myDevice.OutputStream.FlushAsync();

        var responseBufer = (new byte[11]).AsBuffer();
        await myDevice.InputStream.ReadAsync(responseBufer, 11,InputStreamOptions.None);

    }
```

My manifest :

```
<DeviceCapability Name="usb">
        <Device Id="vidpid:0403 6015">
            <Function Type="name:vendorSpecific" />
        </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>

    <DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
        <Device Id="any">
            <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
        </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
```

Thanks for reply

Answer (score 1):

Very late to the discussion, but after running into this same issue, and finding nothing useful in my searches, this is what I concluded...

The problem is that bytes are not actually sent using the write command (at least not immediately).

The call to writer.FlushAsync() does cause the bytes to go out, but then throws a NotImplementedException.

The answer is: writer.StoreAsync().  This causes the bytes to transmit immediately and more importantly, not throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

It said on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.serialcommunication.serialdevice.outputstream.aspx) that "To write data, first get the output stream from the SerialDevice object by using OutputStream property and then use the DataWriter object to write the actual buffer."

So try to use DataWriter instead, your code will be looking like this:

```
var DeviceSelector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
var Devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceSelector);
var deviceInfo = Devices.FirstOrDefault();

SerialDevice myDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);

if (myDevice == null)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Device not found!");
    return;
}
Debug.WriteLine("Device found!");

byte[] buffer = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x05, 0x05, 0x05, 0x05, 0x05 };
var rBuffer = (buffer).AsBuffer();

using (var dataWriter = new DataWriter(myDevice.OutputStream))
{
    dataWriter.WriteBuffer(rBuffer);
}

var responseBufer = (new byte[11]).AsBuffer();
await myDevice.InputStream.ReadAsync(responseBufer, 11, InputStreamOptions.None);
```

Here you don't have to call dataWriter.FlushAsync() because it's suppose to automatically flush while disposing, but if any problems arise - add flushing and check again.